# Integrating WebSocket with Celery and FastAPI in Python

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, celery, python-asyncio, fastapi

**I'm integrating WebSocket with Celery and FastAPI in Python but facing issues like AttributeError and EncodeError. Need help resolving these errors for a seamless integration. Any advice or guidance is appreciated.**

```
@user_router.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    connection = await connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@localhost//")
    async with connection:
        channel = await connection.channel()
        queue = await channel.declare_queue('websocket_queue', durable=True)

        async for message in queue:
            data = message.body.decode('utf-8')
            print("Received message:", data)
            await websocket.send_text(data)
            await message.ack()
```

```
def sync_send_websocket_message(message):
    try:
        print("Sending message:", message)
        connection = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@localhost//"))
        channel = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connection.channel())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(channel.default_exchange.publish(
            message=message,
            routing_key='websocket_queue'
        ))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending WebSocket message:", e)
        raise e

@celery.task
def send_websocket_message(message):
    sync_send_websocket_message(message)
```

```
@user_router.post("/testing_websocket")
def websocket_testing_route(input: dict):
    try:
        task.send_websocket_message.delay("Hello from Celery!")

        return {"message": input}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error occurred in websocket_testing_route: %s", e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sync_send_websocket_message(message):
    try:
        print("Sending message:", message)
        connection = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@localhost//"))
        channel = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connection.channel())
        message_body = json.dumps({"message": message})  # Convert message to JSON string
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(channel.default_exchange.publish(
            Message(body=message_body.encode()),  # Ensure message has a body attribute
            routing_key='websocket_queue'
        ))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending WebSocket message:", e)
        raise e

@celery.task
def send_websocket_message(message):
    sync_send_websocket_message(message)
```

---

```
@user_router.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    connection = await connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@localhost//")
    async with connection:
        channel = await connection.channel()
        queue = await channel.declare_queue('websocket_queue', durable=True)

        async for message in queue:
            data = message.body.decode('utf-8')
            print("Received message:", data)
            await websocket.send_text(data)
            await message.ack()


@user_router.post("/testing_websocket")
def websocket_testing_route(input: dict):
    try:
        task.send_websocket_message.delay("Hello from Celery!")

        return {"message": input}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error occurred in websocket_testing_route: %s", e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")
```

Additional Notes:

- Ensure that the Celery worker environment has network access to the WebSocket server.
- Verify that the WebSocket server is running and reachable from the Celery worker environment.
- Check the WebSocket server logs for any errors or warnings indicating connection issues.

By following these guidelines and making the necessary adjustments, you can seamlessly integrate WebSocket communication with Celery and FastAPI in your Python application.